# JMeter - unable to return correct argument from list in XPath extractor

Tags: jmeter, xpath

In order to generate HTTP requests to open a particular window, I need to obtain the component ID which is nested as an argument in `onmousedown="Console.openView()"` - in this example `componentId= 1325`.

```
<tr>
    <td id="primaryTab6-primaryMenuTab1" class="primaryMenuTab" onmousedown="Console.openView('primaryTab6-primaryMenuTab1', 'portlet.app.tc.management', '1325', false, false, '');" 
                                    onmouseover="Console.hoverMenuItem(this, true);" onmouseout="Console.hoverMenuItem(this, false);">
        <img class="primaryMenuTabIcon" src="/v/css/icons_16/Scale.png">
        <span id="primaryTab6-primaryMenuTab1Label" class="primaryMenuTabLabel">Accounting</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

My XPath currently looks like this:

```
//div/table/tr/td[contains(span,'Accounting')]/onmousedown="Console.openView(@*[3])"
```

But this only returns the with the final argument of `'false'` - no matter what I enter for the match position, it returns the same thing.

I've attempted to tokenize:

```
//div/table/tr/td[contains(span,'Accounting')]/tokenize(@onmousedown="Console.openView"",")[3]
```

However this returns:

> TransformerException: Unknown nodetype: tokenize

I originally was trying to use Regular Expression extractor, but that provided it's own set of difficulties.

Comment: Have you thought of executing a javascript call to interact with the control and then pulling it?  I'm guessing you want to get the value after interaction?

Comment: @mutt that's the next stop on this rabbit hole, learning how to do it via javascript. Trying to pull the ID in a post-processor on when the page loads the menus for use later in the test plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no `tokenize` function in [XPath 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) therefore you won't be able to use it.
2. The `=` operator in XPath compares 2 nodes therefore you will always be getting `false` as left side of expression will never be equal to the right side

I would recommend extracting this `1325` value in 2 steps:

1. Extract the whole `onmousedown` attribute using the following XPath query:

   ```
   //td[contains(span,'Accounting')]/@onmousedown
   ```

   [image: XPath Extractor]
2. Extract `1325` value using [Regular Expression Extractor](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter) like

   ```
   '(\d+)'
   ```

   [image: JMeter REgular Expression]

Comment: Thanks @Dmitiri - running reg ex on the XPath extracted variable works. Will have to investigate a more efficient way of pulling out all the needed componentIds in the future.